# Move forward by angle XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I want to move an object forward, depending on what angle it faces, in this case it's a tank.
So what I want to do is this:
When I press W, the tank has to move forward.
When I press A or D, it rotates the angle.

So far I'm able to rotate the angle but I have no idea on how to make the tank move forward.
I have tried things like.

```
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
{
    TankPos.Y = TankPos.Y - 4;
}
```

But of course, that only makes it go up, no matter the angle. Any simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on spenders answer, and depending if you are using fixed time step or not, you also need to multiply the delta with the time elapsed since the last frame.

```
var deltaX = Math.Sin(angleRad) * tankSpeed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
var deltaY = -Math.Cos(angleRad) * tankSpeed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
```

(Milliseconds or Seconds, depending on which measurement you use for your tank speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 0,0 is top left and 0 degrees is up:

```
var deltaX = Math.Sin(angleRad) * distance;
var deltaY = -Math.Cos(angleRad) * distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you rotating the camera or the tank when you a/d? If you only rotate the tank, it will quickly go off the camera. If you are rotating the camera then you can use the x and y components of the camera's direction vector to get a direction for the tank to move in.